# Running a Python file on command prompt launches vscode instead

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-prompt

I'm trying to launch a python script on windows command prompt, but instead of it doing it, it opens the script on vscode instead. I searched the options in vscode and didn't find anything. How can I stop this behavior?

SOLVED

I simply changed the default program for `.py` files

Comment: What command do you use to launch it?

Comment: To solve it, set python.exe as the default app for py files, then modify `PATHEXT` environment variable to include `.PY` extension. Then you can execute python scripts directly with `./my_script.py`

Comment: @abdusco I just navigated to the containing folder and typed in the file's name. also just changing the default program solved it, so thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to **change the default application for `.py` files to `python.exe`**.
This will instruct Windows to pass the filename of the python script you're trying to open to `python.exe`, which will execute it.

```
python my_script.py
```

As a bonus, if you change the `PATHEXT` environment variable to include `.py` extension. This will allow you to run a python script without prefixing it with `python` command when working in a shell.

```
./my_script.py
```

Python installer does this by default, but if it isn't there, you can add it.